# How to set default implementation for multiple profiles in Spring?

Tags: java, spring

For example, I have many profiles, "dev", "prod", "test", etc.

```
interface A

@Component
class DefaultImpl implements A

@Profile("test")
@Component
class TestImpl implements A
```

I want TestImpl only for the profile "test", but DefaultImpl for all the other profiles.

UPDATE:
Why @Profile("default") is not working for me:

I have two test profiles, i.e. "test1" and "test2"

I provided a different implementation in profile "test1":

```
@Profile("default")
class DefaultImpl extends A

@Profile("test1")
class Test1Impl extends A
```

now when I @ActivateProfile("test2"), it won't pick DefaultImpl

However if I don't set the profile, like this:

```
class DefaultImpl extends A

@Profile("test1")
class Test1Impl extends A
```

profile "test2" will end up having two beans and don't know which to wire.

Right now, only this will work:

```
@Profile("test2", "prod", ....)
class DefaultImpl extends A

@Profile("test1")
class Test1Impl extends A
```

Is there anything I can do other than adding all the other profile names in DefaultImpl ?

Answer (score 1):

If you do not specify a profile you will get the "default" profile.

So in your example DefaultImpl  will be loaded if you use no profile.  If you set the profile to test with :

```
@ActiveProfiles("test") or -Dspring.profiles.active=test
```

You will get bot DefaultImpl and TestImpl

You can change to make sure DefaultImpl does not run for test:

```
@Profile("default")
@Component
class DefaultImpl implements A
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `@Profile("default")` on DefaultImpl.

Or, alternatively, you can create a specific named default and specify it in your web.xml:

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>spring.profiles.default</param-name>
    <param-value>mydefault<param-value>
</context-param>
```